# why main() is not necessary in action classes of struts2 ?

Tags: java, struts2, javabeans

**Hello Guys..! **

Normally a java program needs main() function to execute the code otherwise it'll returns an error[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread "main"]..! In struts2 we are using action classes & bean classes(java codes) but they don't needs main() function in it. What is the concept behind this..? By the way I'm a newbie to the Struts framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Struts framework provides the infrastructure to get the application up and running. As a user of the framework, you implement specific classes that are called by the framework code.

Struts itself runs inside an application server such as Tomcat, and usually it is the server that contains the `main()` method which is ultimately responsible for starting up your application.

This is an example of [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) -- many application frameworks work this way.

Answer (score 0):

You need a main() method in applications started from the command line as that's the API that the JVM expects to execute in that case.  Code called from within other frameworks must implement whatever API that framework expects.  In many cases that framework implements main() and calls your code via some other API.  This is usually more robust than `public void main(String[] args)` allows.  In other instances the framework is itself called from another abstraction (e.g. a Web Application within a Web Framework within a App Container).

Comment: thank you very much for your Answer, I have clarified my doubt..!